# Moniter HTML5 applet data usage

Tags: javascript, php, apache

I am working on a HTML 5 applet that we use for all our quotes and customer data tracking. The people using it on the road complain about high data usage on their mobile. I am already gzipping everything server side and caching all of the resource files and caching the image files for 15 days.

Is there a way in JS to track all download data or server side in PHP track bytes sent per call? I know how I can track all my ajax calls but I'd like a universal function that also tracks page load amounts and image sizes to really track down where I should improve the overall data usage.

example... `document.onitemloaded = function(){};`

server is a centos 7 with apache and PHP 7

Comment: Did you try to open the browser's console - specifically its network tab?

Comment: Yes I can check my own data usage when testing. I would like to see the real world application so I'm not left guessing